# Given a group, how to show the distributive law and some examples (does the distributive law have to be an axiom?)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

tl;dr: What properties does a set need for it to have the distributive law? Does it need to be an axiom?

Given a group (i.e. satisfies the closure, associative, inverse and identity properties/axioms), how do you show the distributive law? i.e is the distributive law a consequence of being a group or does it have to be an axiom? Does every group has as property the distributive law?

Say we have a group $(Z,+)$

How do you show:

$$
ab+ac=a(b+c)
$$

What threw me off a little was that the group was not defined under multiplication, so I was not sure what to try. A proof of the distributive property is what I am looking for. Also, I trying to gain intuition on why some operations do not distribute under some groups. Examples and reasons are welcome and helpful!

The following made me ask this question:

I have a book on number theory and group theory and it stated the following:

Theorem 6.4. Let G be an abelian group. Then for all $a, b \in G$ and $k, l \in Z$, we
have:

$$(i) \ k(la) = (kl)a = l(ka)$$
$$(ii) \ (k + l)a = ka + la$$
$$(iii) \ k(a + b) = ka + kb$$

And they leave the proof as an exercise, which I wanted to try and do. However, I was not sure how to even start because a group is defined under one operation but the expression provided show two operations. Also, I thought, that the distributive property was not bound only to abelian groups, thats why I didn't include the word abelian in my question.

Comment: What is $\cdot $ if your group has only $+$? Is $a$ supposed to be an element of $Z$ or possibly an element of $\mathbb Z$ (all abelian groups are $\mathbb Z$-modules)

Comment: The axioms of a group do not include distributivity. The distributive law requires two operations.

Comment: @Pinocchio It will hardly be a *group* under both operations.

Comment: The distributive law is an axiom for _rings_ and _fields_; the multiplication operation need not define a group for such objects. (In fact, it almost never does!)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein so, the distributive property is not a consequence of being a group? i.e. every group is NOT distributive? Does it need to be assumed as an axiom for the set?

Comment: @Pinocchio Here, $ka$ does *not* mean the product of $k$ and $a$, it means $a+a+a+\dots+a$ $k$ times.

Comment: Oh. That explains everything. Thanks so much. Does that mean that, the above properties are **not** the distributive law then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure, but I think that there's a misunderstanding about what this multiplication is.

Since the group operation is $+$, the "power" is $\cdot$.

Written in multiplicative notation, what you want to prove is:
$$(a^l)^k = a^{kl} = (a^k)^l$$
$$a^{k+l} = a^k a^l$$
$$(ab)^k = a^k b^k$$

As for the proofs, proceed by induction on $k$ and $l$.

Comment: Basically, ka does not mean the product of k and a, it means a+a+a+⋯+a k times. That was my misunderstanding. Do the other properties still count as the distributive law? Thanks! :D

Comment: It looks like it, but I wouldn't call it that, because they are from different sets. Also, at least in my experience, distributive implies there's a ring involved, which there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group with neutral element $e$ and let $X$ be a set. We say that $G$ **acts on the set** $X$ if we are given a map $G\times X\to X$, $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$ if the following natural requirements are fulfilled: $(g\circ h)\cdot x = g\cdot(h\cdot x)$ and $e\cdot x=x$ for all $g,h\in G$, $x\in X$. (The first requirement may allow one to be sloppy and use the same multiplication symbol for the group operation and the action and also drop parentheses).

If $X$ carries additional structure, say $(X,*)$ is also a group, we - naturally - demand that more requirements be respected before we say that the group $(G,\circ)$ **acts on the group** $(X,*)$, namely that $g\cdot(x*y)=(g\cdot x)*(g\cdot y)$. Note that this *looks* like the distributive law, but $g,x,y$ are (usually) not from the same set!

If $(X,*)$ is an *abelian* group with neutral element $e$, then there is always a standard way to define an action of the additive group $(\mathbb Z,+)$ on it:
Define $0\cdot x=e$ first, then by the recursion $(n+1)\cdot x=(n\cdot x)*x$ define the action of all positive integers and finally by $(-n)\cdot x=(n\cdot x)^{-1}$ the action of negative integers. (Verify that this is an action, be careful with all those different operation symbols!).
If we are a bit sloppy and use $+$ also for the group operation of $X$ (and negation for inverse), as is usual for abelian groups, then the fact that $(\mathbb Z,+)$ acts on the group $(X,+)$ precisely formalizes that "distributivity" holds.

As $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is also an abelian group, the above method can be used to define an action of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ on itself. We should be careful because  we use $\cdot$ to denote this action and already have an intrinsic multiplication of integers that is also written with $\cdot$. Fortunately, the group action of $(\mathbb Z ,+)$ on itself is precisely the normal integer multiplication (check that without getting confused about the different operations).

As a bonus check that $(n\cdot m)\cdot x=n\cdot (m\cdot x)$ holds for all $n,m\in \mathbb Z$ and $x\in X$ with the group action of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ on the abelian group $(X,*)$ defined above, justifying again the use of the same symbol for both things (and allowing one to drop parentheses) even though they are strictly speaking not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be very careful about what you're saying.

First of all, can you give an example of a group that doesn't satisfy "*the closure, associative, inverse and identity properties/axioms*"? That's the very definition of a group!

Secondly, What does $\times$ mean in the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$? A group only has a single operation. Take the set of homeomorphisms between a topological space and itself. They form a group under composition (do one and then do the other). How do you add and multiply homeomorphisms?

Thirdly, even if you stick to an example where $+$ and $\times$ have their usual meanings. You might not get a group when you change the operation. For example $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group while $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$ is not a group (what is $0^{-1}$?).

Finally, I think you want to know about the idea of a field. See here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Sorry, I know thats the definition of a group, I was just trying to provide its definition to remind people.

Comment: @Pinocchio That's fair enough. In this case, a rule of thumb: if someone doesn't know what a group is then they probably won't be able to answer your question. It's good to give descriptions, e.g. $(G,\cdot)$ is a group, but definitions aren't needed.